# Magento2: How to get online customer collection list?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-collection

I want to get online or logged In customer collection list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this below code for get online customer list :

**Way 1 :**

```
protected $onlineColl;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Online\Grid\CollectionFactory $onlineCollFactory
){
    $this->onlineCollFactory = $onlineCollFactory;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $customerSession = $this->onlineCollFactory->create();
    echo "<pre/>";
    print_r($customerSession->getData());
    exit;
}
```

**Way 2 :**

```
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Online\Grid\Collection');
        $customerData = $customerSession->getData();
        echo "<pre/>";
        print_r($customerData);
        exit;
```

Remove generated and clean cache.

Comment: I will check and update you soon. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Is it done?

Comment: It is working fine but i want to show registered customer only.

Comment: Please check the screenshot https://prnt.sc/ruitwk. If i have logout then customer should be not show in the list.

Comment: How to show registered online user only?

Comment: Let me check that.

Comment: You have got any solution.

Comment: Sorry. Right now, Lil bit busy in other stuff so. You can ask new question for that. Maybe someone help you.

Comment: Ok, No problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get logged in customer data in Magento 2,Refer here - https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/

Comment: I want to logged In customer collection list. Not need customer data.

Comment: Check this answer , if its relevant https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173530/magento-2-check-customer-logged-in-or-not-on-basis-of-customer-id

Comment: It is not working.